# Iterate over angular custom directive's children

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I had the following list before:

```
<ul id="#expenses">
    <li></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And I could reach the object as

```
var expenses = angular.element('#expenses')
```

Then, since an HTML list has children, I could iterate over it as

```
angular.forEach(expenses.children('li'), function(...))
```

However, I had to place a custom tag inside this list and my HTML became:

```
<ul id="#expenses">
    <submenu>
        <li></li>
        ...
    </submenu>
</ul>
```

Now I can reach the list as:

```
var expenses = document.querySelector('#expenses > submenu')
```

However, children() function does not work. Console says that expenses.children('li') is not a function. In this case, how can I iterate over `<li>` tags inside a custom `<submenu>` tag?

Comment: I think you have loaded `jQuery` after `angularjs`, do load jQuery before angular will fix this.. angular has inbuild smaller version of jQuery which is `jQLite`, which has `children` method but that doesn't support selector value.. for more info look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: @PankajParkar Angularjs already has jQuery lite with it  so you don't have to load it!

Comment: @PeterWilson yes sir. do look at my udpated comment, it doesn't support selector based query

Comment: First of all it is not allowed in HTML to use `<submenu>` as a child of `<ul>`. The only direct children of `<ul>` should be `<li>` tags. Btw, is `<submenu>` not a directive?

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes you are right for sure!